# iOS 10 - UIImagePickerController for both Photos and Camera

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When a user pulls up their sms app in iOS 10 and clicks on the camera icon, a pickerview comes up that allows users to either click on a photo from their library or snap a picture from the same view. Is there anything in Swift 3 that would allow third party applications to utilize this type of ImagePickerController? As of now I am only aware of the methods that allow apps to designate the photo library or camera exclusively as the source type.

Comment: The iOS SDK does not provide such a control. You will have to write it yourself or find a library someone else wrote to replicate the same feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think iMessage's app doesn't use UIImagePickerController to implement that feature you metioned.

Use Photos.framework and AVFoundation.framework can create your expected UIViewController.

UIImagePickerController is just a simple high-level controller which is lack functions and less customization. It's hard to make complicated interfaces with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [ALCameraViewController](https://github.com/AlexLittlejohn/ALCameraViewController) in one of my apps before. It allows you to take photos, crop, and there is a button to pick images from the library. Just add the pod to your project.

> **Usage**
>
> To use this component couldn't be simpler. Add import
>   ALCameraViewController to the top of you controller file.
>
> In the viewController
>
> ```
> let croppingEnabled = true
> let cameraViewController = CameraViewController(croppingEnabled: croppingEnabled) { [weak self] image, asset in
>     // Do something with your image here.
>     // If cropping is enabled this image will be the cropped version
>
>     self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
> }
>
> present(cameraViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
> ```